# ¿Cómo copiar ciertos valores de un vector en Bash?

Tags: array, bash

Tengo mi vector:

```
cadena=(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)
```

trato de copiar los 1 en otro vector de la siguiente forma:

```
nuevo=("${cadena[@]/0/}")
```

pero al imprimir

```
echo ${#nuevo[@]}
```

me salen 7 elementos 
pero al hacer

```
echo ${nuevo[@]}
```

solo me salen 5 elementos,los 1
y haciendo

```
echo ${nuevo[4]} ;echo ${nuevo[3]}
```

me sale nada , supongo que es de los 0 
¿Cómo podria hacer para copiar solo los 1? , porque veo que de esa forma a pesar que los 0 se eliminan su espacio en el vector no se ha modificado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando dices `${variable/X/Y}` lo que estás produciendo es una substitución de cadenas: allá donde hay una X, queda una Y. En concreto, si Y está vacío lo que haces es eliminar ese carácter:

```
$ v="hola"
$ echo ${v/h/}
ola
```

Sin embargo, esto es una acción sobre las cadenas, nada tiene que ver con los elementos del array. Es decir, lo que estás haciendo es sustituir los elementos "0" en el vector por la cadena vacía:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${v[@]}"
1
2
3
$ printf "%s\n" "${v[@]/1/}"

2
3
```

Lo que es equivalente a definir:

```
$ v=("" 2 3)
$ printf "%s\n" "${v[@]/1/}"
2
3
```

Esto explica lo que pasa. Ahora veamos qué puedes hacer.

#### Filtrar valores en un array en bash

Lo que debes utilizar es la sintaxis:

```
${array[@]/elemento_a_eliminar}
```

Es decir, la misma que utilizabas pero sin la última `/`.

Veamos un ejemplo en el que eliminamos el elemento "1":

```
$ v=(1 2 3 4 1 2)
$ printf "%s\n" ${v[@]/1}
2
3
4
2
```

Esto está explicado en el [Bash Reference Manual -> 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> **${parameter/pattern/string}**
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern
>   against its value is replaced with string. If pattern begins with ‘/’,
>   all matches of pattern are replaced with string. Normally only the
>   first match is replaced. If pattern begins with ‘#’, it must match at
>   the beginning of the expanded value of parameter. If pattern begins
>   with ‘%’, it must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter.
>   **If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be omitted**. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the
>   substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in
>   turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an
>   array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the substitution operation
>   is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is
>   the resultant list.

En tu caso, por tanto, usarás:

```
$ cadena=(1 1 1 0 0 1 1)
$ nuevo=(${cadena[@]/0})
$ printf "%s\n" "${nuevo[@]}"
1
1
1
1
1
```